# Error LDAP authentication with Jasig Cas on Active Directory

Tags: cas, jasig

I am getting the following tomcat error in my log when I try to login to CAS. Can anyone help me where my error might be? Configuration of CAS an Active Directory is as standard as can be, only exception is I am using ldap instead of ldaps.

> 2013-09-27 01:26:19,714 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 4 services.
>   2013-09-27 01:26:22,651 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
>   2013-09-27 01:26:40,806 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Beginning ticket cleanup.
>   2013-09-27 01:26:40,822 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - 0 tickets found to be removed.
>   2013-09-27 01:26:40,822 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Finished ticket cleanup.
>   2013-09-27 01:28:19,820 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Reloading registered services.
>   2013-09-27 01:28:19,820 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 4 services.
>   2013-09-27 01:30:19,778 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Reloading registered services.
>   2013-09-27 01:30:19,778 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 4 services.
>   2013-09-27 01:30:55,688 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /cas/
>   2013-09-27 01:30:55,688 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /cas/
>   2013-09-27 01:31:18,878 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler threw error authenticating [username: pieter@test.local]
>   org.springframework.ldap.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001CD, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
>       'DC=test,DC=local'
>       NULL]; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-031001CD, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT), data 0, best match of:
>       'DC=test,DC=local'
>   NULL]; remaining name 'DC=USERS,DC=test,DC=local'
>       at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:174)
>       at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:361)
>       at org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.authenticateUsernamePasswordInternal(BindLdapAuthenticationHandler.java:90)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler.doAuthentication(AbstractUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler.java:71)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody2(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:85)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody3$advice(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:57)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(AbstractPreAndPostProcessingAuthenticationHandler.java:1)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticateAndObtainPrincipal(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:93)
>       at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody0(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:57)
>           ...

Comment: The message says your directory doesn't contain "DC=test,DC=local". Have you checked what is actually there?

Comment: It would be helpful to post the applicable parts of the deployerConfig.xml file.

Comment: It was CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local instead of DC=users,DC=test,DC=local The CAS examples on the site are wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was `CN=Users,DC=test,DC=local` instead of `DC=users,DC=test,DC=local` The CAS examples on the site are wrong.